# Apex Trigger For New Child From Field Update

Tags: apex, trigger

My goal is to enable my team to update a particular field on the Opportunity Object (Stage__c) to 'Closed Won', and have that auto-generate a new custom child object (Onboarding) that is linked to the same account that the Opportunity is linked to.

At this point, I have produced the following trigger but am continuously prompt with

> "Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Stage__c for SObject Opportunity
>   at line 6 column 17"

Below is my entire trigger.  Any thoughts/advice are greatly appreciated!

```
trigger CreateOB on Account (after insert, after update) {
    Onboarding__c[] inserts = new Onboarding__c[] {};
    for (Opportunity a : Trigger.new) {
        if (a.Stage__c == 'Closed Won') {
            Account old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
            if (a.Stage__c != old.Stage__c) {
                inserts.add(new Onboarding__c(Account_Name__c = a.Id));
            }
        }
    }
    insert inserts;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Trigger is on account but you are Assigning `trigger.new` to the Opportunity sObject in your for loop

The error means there is no field named `Stage__c` on the Opportunity Object

Are you sure you have created a custom field named Stage? Or are you trying to update the standard field Stage. If the latter, the API name of the standard Field is `StageName`

It may also be fixed by changing Opportunity to Account in the for loop as that may be what you meant to have. (Only if Stage__c exists on Account

Comment: Hi Eric,

Thanks for all of your help on this!  I updated my trigger based on your comments above and below but now I am seeing a new error.  You were correct that I was using the wrong field value, mental hiccup I suppose.  Now the problem seems to be that I am attempting to create an Onboarding page (custom child obj) from a field change on the Opportunity page (child obj) and have the new Onboarding page linked to the same Account that the Opportunity was linked to.  In my next comment will be the code I currently have and the error I am receiving.

Comment: trigger CreateOB on Account (after insert, after update) {
    Onboarding__c[] inserts = new Onboarding__c[] {};
    for (Opportunity a : Trigger.new) {
        if (a.StageName == 'Closed Won') {
            Opportunity old = Trigger.oldMap.get(a.Id);
            if (a.StageName != old.StageName) {
                inserts.add(new Onboarding__c(Account_Name__c = a.Id));
            }
        }
    }
    insert inserts;
}

Answer (score -1):

Since your trigger is on the Account object, your `trigger.new` list will contain a list of accounts that the trigger is running on. So you're basically trying to check the `Stage__c` field on the Account object, which doesn't exist.

Not sure what your process is, but 2 options are available here:

1) Change your trigger to be on Opportunity

2) Replace `trigger.new` with a SOQL query in order to obtain the opportunity's `Stage__c` field:

`for (Account a : [SELECT Id, Opportunity.Stage__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :trigger.newMap.keySet()])`

and then

`if (a.Opportunity.Stage__c == 'Closed Won')
// your code here`

Comment: Even so, the compiler did not get to the part about the invalid assignment to opportunity. It is stuck on the fact that Stage__c is not a valid field for Opportunity so your a.Opportunity.Stage__c should still produce the same error. Not to mention you cannot access Opportunity like you are doing in the query

Comment: Can you please check the field level security on that field and make sure it's visible for the profile?